# Would I typically get a shock from touching two live wires separated by ~240 V with each hand if my skin were completely dry (assume I'm ungrounded)?

Tags: voltage, current, resistance, shock

As the question asks, would I? I'm aware that one should naturally never actually try this, and that people for the most part do get shocked when accidentally doing this, but why exactly is that? I just recently measured the resistance of my body from hand to hand at ~1.6 megaohms, so at 240 V that corresponds to a 150 microamperes of current. That type of current shouldn't even be enough to harm my heart even if it went straight through it as far as I'm aware. I also read that the breakdown voltage for skin was ~500 volts, so 240 volts shouldn't be enough for that, or is there perhaps some partial breakdown effect that needs to be accounted for? Or is it perhaps because the peak-to-peak voltage is high enough to cause breakdown?

Comment: _"I also read that the breakdown voltage for skin was ~500 volts"_ No such thing. Skin resistance varies from person to person and how hydrated he/she is. 240 V is potentially lethal, especially from hand to hand as the current will pass though the heart. Don't!

Comment: As for "harm the heart" it all depends on exactly when the electric shock hits the heart in the duration of the heart cycle. One reason why some die and some don't... And apparently 0.2V can be sufficient to stop the heart - see heart cycle...

Comment: @winny: Even if it varies from person to person I would assume there would be a breakdown voltage, though; but another answer says the skin resistance is non-linear and would be much less at higher voltages well before 500 V. I was basing my statement on this study: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2763825/ "At 500 V or more, high resistance in the outer layer of the skin breaks down.3 This lowers the body's resistance to current flow greatly. The result is an increase in the amount of current that flows with any given voltage."

Comment: Your initial statement was that nothing would happen below 500 V due to skin breakdown, this isn’t the case. The skin resistance is low enough for 240 V to be lethal. What happens above 500 V does not matter.

Comment: @winny: What I said was that I read the breakdown voltage of skin was at ~500 V; if skin were to maintain its full resistance before that point given that assumption, then I would further have assumed my calculation would have been correct. 1.6 megaohms at 240 V does not seem nearly enough current to be lethal, as it would correspond to 150 microamperes of current.

Comment: Human body model per MIL-STD-883H is 1.5 kohm.

Comment: @winny: I'm sure that's generally true, but when I measured the resistance from hand to hand it was 1.6 megaohms, and from reading it's not uncommon to read such values for dry and intact skin. So, will there be partial breakdown long before 500 V leading to increased current, or would the resistance in that circumstance be sufficient to avoid serious problems?

Comment: Your are using the word breakdown. Two conductors separated by air has a breakdown voltage. A semiconductor has a breakdown voltage. Before the breakdown voltage of both, practically no current is flowing. In human skin, you have resistance from zero volt and current flowing.

Comment: Yes, and in this case if my skin were to have 1.6 megaohms of resistance until some partial or complete breakdown, then 240 V wouldn't be nearly enough to cause damage. Thus my point is that I assume that the skin resistance partially or completely breaks down well before that.

Comment: I would not be willing to bet my life on it.

Comment: @winny: I agree, naturally; this is purely hypothetical, I'm not going to be touching any live wires anytime soon, at least not on purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: generally, yes. It may or may not be fatal (in fact most people survive from 220/240V exposition), but you can bet it will be quite unpleasant.

I don't know how you did measure your resistance, but take my word that you are very much non-linear resistor and your resistance at 240V is orders of magnitude less than your resistance at (half the voltage of the multimeter battery minus whatever electrochemical voltage loss between the metal and the body, generally about 1.5V).

What's worse, the surface skin resistance (it dominates your hand-to-hand measured value) tends to be temperature-dependent and gets much lower as the passing current heats the point of contact. This is how unlucky people get burns in addition to the electric shock.

Comment: Going from hand to hand will be more than just 'unpleasant' if you grab the wires, because you won't be able to let go, and the result will probably be fatal. I have a hole in my thumb due to contacting 240V. Luckily it was only across one hand, else I wouldn't be here to type this.

Answer (score 0):

Skin resistance is not constant and [depends on a number of factors](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/skin-resistance)

> Consistency of the skin, that is, whether it is dry or moist.
>
> Contact pressure; that is, increasing pressure reduces skin
> resistance.
>
> Contact area; that is, the larger is the area, the lower the skin
> resistance.
>
> It also has been reported that cuts or punctures can reduce skin
> resistance to values for wet skin or even below. Because of its
> variable nature, a conservative and safe approach is to consider skin
> resistance negligible.
>
> Body impedance is an important factor, but it appears to be nonlinear
> with voltage.

So a resistance meter reading will have a very small contact area and show a larger resistance. Also, that resistance will be at the low test voltage.

Comment: Right, but the question is what the actual resistance would be at a larger voltage, assuming ideal conditions of the skin (quite dry, no cuts or punctures). The source I found stated that breakdown voltage was at 500 V, while others say that it is indeed nonlinear with voltage as the last point you just posted mentions. I've also seen some people claim that it's relevant that peak voltage is higher, but peak voltage of ~240 V RMS AC is still "only" 340 V. I'm obviously not going to try touching any live wire, I'm just curious as to whether it's a given that you'd be shocked or not.

Comment: @OutisNemo Well, I can tell you from experience the answer is "yes" - a live wire and dry skin will still give a shock. Also, as the skin area in contact with the conductor increases you are effectively paralleling resistors

Comment: I don't doubt that you typically do get a shock, although I would guess most people don't actually have personal experience touching two live wires with separate hands, not even electricians; however, what I'm asking is why that is when considering what I've mentioned so far, and whether or not you are bound to get a shock every time or whether it's possible to avoid it under ideal circumstances. When I measured 1.6 megaohms of resistance I was holding the pins of the multimeter between my fingers, so under the same assumption I'd be holding the wires in the same way, same surface area.

Comment: @OutisNemo Well, if you want to try something very dangerous, which I do not recommend, then try feeling the mains voltage through a 10nF XY mains rated capacitor. The impedance is around 300k so you should get about 1mA max. Have a friend on the switch and ambulance on speed dial.

Comment: I'm certainly not going to try anything like that; this is purely hypothetical. I'm just trying to understand the actual factors at play here. I still don't understand why I would get shocked if my skin is in ideal condition (dry, no cuts/bruises) and I touch the wires with the same surface area that I'm touching the measuring pins I'm using to measure my resistance. That is, unless skin resistance breaks down at lower voltages than 500 V, but no one has yet given me a good explanation of how exactly that works.